# Задать градиент с помощью css в свойстве border

Tags: html, css

У меня есть `div` элемент и он существует в границах. Весь контент внутри данного блока централизуется. Проблема заключается в том, что я не понимаю как задать градиент и установить данный стиль, который приведен ниже. Он работает отлично для `hr`

```
/* Gradient transparent - color - transparent */

hr.style-two {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

Как мне сделать тоже самое и для моего блока с границами?

```
<div class="category_header">
  Random text
</div>
```

Я написал данный `css`, который убирает границы по бокам. Границы находятся только сверху и снизу, но как мне применить градиент к ним?

```
.category_header {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px black;
    border-style: solid none;
}
```

Я пытался использовать `border-image`

```
.category_header {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px black;
    border-style: solid none;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

Но границы пропадают

Answer (score 0):

Я решил данную проблему так

```
.category_header {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px transparent;
    border-style: solid none;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    border-image-slice: 1;
}
```